# How to authenticate Google Blogger using HttpWebrequest in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, blogger, win-universal-app

I find this below code using Blogger API v3..

this below code is working but the problem is, it is asking for blogger login to user. I used this code in Apps then how the user login into my blogger..

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new Uri("ms-appx:///Json/client_secret.json"),
                    new[] { BloggerService.Scope.Blogger },
                    "lartpeopleindiancinema@gmail.com",
                    CancellationToken.None);

                var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Admin Site Old",
                };

                service = new BloggerService(initializer);
```